# FormData - array from HTML

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to send data to Java servlet using XHTMLHttpRequest object. The data is in form, so I decided to use FormData object. However something doesn't work I cannot read the data in Java servlet.

My HTML:

```
<form id="formTable" action="Calc" method="GET">
    <input type="submit" value="GET">
    <input type="button" onclick="sendRequest()" value="AJAX">
    <table id="valuesTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>x</td>
                <td>sin(x)</td>
                <td>cos(x)</td>
            <tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <td><input type="number" name="args[]" step=0.0001 value=0 required></td><td>0</td><td>0</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="args[]" step=0.0001 value=0 required></td><td>0</td><td>0</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="args[]" step=0.0001 value=0 required></td><td>0</td><td>0</td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

And sendRequest function:

```
function sendRequest() {  
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var formElement = document.getElementById("formTable");
    var formData = new FormData(formElement);
    console.log(formData);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {
            processResponse(this);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "Calc", true);
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
}
```

In Java servlet I'm using `String argument[] = request.getParameterValues("args[]");` to read the values. It works for standard form submition (through 'GET' button). However when I do it from JavaScript level with XHTMLHttpRequest the `argument` object in Java is **null**. What am I doing wrong? My best guess is that somehow my `formData` object doesn't work as expected, but why?

Comment: Use `FormData()` constructor without argument.

Comment: @RomanC I tried without any success. But anyway how was it supposed to work without constructor argument?

Comment: I've used `FormData` to upload blob object, and it worked, I think it is similar to other input fields, but this way you don't need to work with `<form>` element.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to send the `formData` with a GET request it is simply ignored. You will need to use POST instead:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "Calc", true);
xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

Also the request is sent as `multipart/form-data` and therefore `HttpServletRequest.getPart(s)` must be used to read the parameters.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem (POST request is handled in the same way as GET request in my servlet).